# Ceiling fan won’t change speeds

Tags: ceiling-fan, remote-control

Have an outdoor Minka Aire ceiling fan that has a wall switch (only supplying power; no other controls) and a remote used to change speeds on the fan. After working for about 3 years it will no longer change speeds or turn on/off with the remote. It’s just stuck on medium speed. Tried resetting remote several times according to directions found on internet but still doesn’t work. Ordered replacement remote without success either. It’s like the ceiling fan receiver is not seeing the remote. Any ideas on what the problem could be? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If the fan has pull-chain switch control of speed, make sure the pull switch is in the highest setting. This is reqd to allow the remote to control the speed. To test if the remote transmitter/receiver is at fault, disconnect the receiver and connect the wires directly as if you have no remote. Does the pull-chain change the speed?

Comment: The sensor of the receiver on the fan might have dirt on it or the receiver itself is broken/not connected anymore.

Comment: I just dealt with a Minka Aire that had paper instructions completely wrong. Called tech support and they set me right in about 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. The fan has worked for a few years up until a few months ago. @JimStewart Unfortunately, the fan does not have a pull chain.

Comment: @crip659 Where would I find the sensor on the receiver so I can check to see if it's dirty?

Comment: When you got the new remote did you have to open it and set it for the same code as the original remote?

Comment: So the fan is running constantly if the wall switch is on? If you turn off the wall switch does the fan stop and then start again on medium when you turn the switch back on? Have you turned off the breaker in the panel for 2 min and then turned it back on and tried the remote?

Comment: The receiver/on-off/speed control switch is probably all electronic and has no mechanical contacts. It is probably a box loose under the shroud at the ceiling, but might built into the fan circuitry. If it is a separate box connected by wire nuts, you could bypass the receiver and the fan should be on high speed if the fault is in the receiver switch. – Jim Stewart 7 mins ago   Delete